# How to find the original from a cropped image

Tags: image, image-processing

Hei guys. I want to do a application regarding image processing but I dont know what to read first. The ideea is that I want to find from a cropped image the original one. For example unploading this image [image]

i want to detect this one [image]

edit: TO be more precisely. I'll have a database full of images and I want to find the original from the cropped one . What algorithms I can use to do that?
I'll use c++ or c#. Haven't decided yet.

Comment: What lang/environment? Take a look at the features offered by opencv for template matching http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Answer (score 0):

Most image searching applications, I THINK use something line [LOcality Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) , I dont know which language your using, but i am a Ruby developer and there's a gem called [Recommendify](https://github.com/paulasmuth/recommendify) that might do the magic.

Comment: Ok. that's a start. I'll use probably c++ or c#