# Reverse engineering image crop and resize

Tags: java, image-processing

I have two images. A is a high resolution image. B is a cropped low resolution version of A.

What I need is a library or set of libraries which could allow me to find the crop+resize information given these two images.

Pseudo code to help explain the scenario is:

```
Crop cropInfo = findCrop(originalImageA, lowResImageB)
```

A bonus would be if the libraries involved run on the JVM!

Comment: If this is off topic please suggest where I could post this instead.

Comment: Also discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610508/how-to-find-the-original-from-a-cropped-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use openCV to help you: 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Here's openCV in Java:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html